# How to return null when the Linq query returns empty value?

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I have the following code to get values from the list.

```
GetList().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "MyKey").MyValue;
```

When there is `Key` property with value `MyKey` in a list it is working fine but when there is not `Key` property with value `MyKey` in a list it is throwing an  `NullReferenceException`. How can I return null value instead of exception.

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use ?. and ?[]  [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) Operators. It tests the value of the left-hand operand for null before performing a member access (?.) or index (?[]) operation; returns null if the left-hand operand evaluates to null.

```
GetList().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "MyKey")?.MyValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code

```
var result = GetList().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "MyKey");
if(result != null)
{
  //Add your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More safe way to handle the Null in the LINQ.

```
GetList().Where(x => x.Key == "MyKey").Select(S=>S.MyValue).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi Kalpesh can you explain how this code handle the null exception